# Is there a way to resize an MdiTab to fit your newly-updated text? (Infragistics)

Tags: resize, infragistics, mdi, autoresize, fontmetrics

I am resetting the text for an MdiTab in an UltraWinTabbedMdi. I reset it to be bold and longer, but the tab does not resize so the text is truncated. Right now, I'm just resetting the size of the tab to some magic number that I've found looks decent on my computer, but I don't know if it will work elsewhere. I would like to be able to get the dimensions of the new text and add the same size to that every time or call some auto-resize method.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the MeasureString of the Graphics class.

```
// Set up string.
string measureString = "YourText";
// The font name and size used to draw the string (from your MdiTab)
Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

// Measure string.
SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
stringSize = this.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

// now you have a stringSize.Width and stringSize.Height to use
```

Comment: I had gotten most of the way before. The part I was running into trouble with was grabbing the "Graphics". I hadn't thought of just grabbing the Graphics from the form. I'm using VB.Net and the way I did it was to use "Me.CreateGraphics()".